# Accessing Leaflet.js GeoJson features from outside

Tags: javascript, dictionary, leaflet, geo

I want to interact with a leaflet powered map's GeoJson overlay (polygons) from outside of `L.`'s realm, but I don't seem to be able to access objects created by `L.`.

Interaction would include:

- getBounds(myFeature)
- fitBounds(myFeature)
- setStyle
  etc

I can see Leaflet exposing L.GeoJSON.getFeature(), but I don't seem to be able to squeeze anything out of it. No documentation, and the inspector seems to suggest it does not take arguments... :\

Is this just there for future development?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may use getLayer to get the feature by its id.
http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup-getlayer

```
var geojsonLayer = L.geoJson(data,{
    onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer._leaflet_id = feature.id;                                    
    }});
geojsonLayer.addTo(map);

feature = geojsonLayer.getLayer(12345); //your feature id here
alert(feature.feature.id);
```

Comment: It seems like the logical place to go / look, but I cannot get it info out. Do you happen to have an example I could look at?

Comment: Sorry, been completly hijacked with another project.I am yet to hook in some of functions, but I can now access Leaflet's objects from external input. Thanks for your help.